# Can we trigger a telegram bot inside a group chat using a link?

Tags: javascript, telegram, telegram-bot

Firstly hello, so i wrote a referral bot using node-telegram-bot-api, it read some values regarding the question is, at the end it generate a link, that include a user (TL username) as params for the start command, another user will use it to have as a referral link with the parent.

now everything works fine in a private mode with bot.

e.g. of referral link that works: [https://t.me/?start=<parent/ref>](https://t.me)

the question is:
I added the bot to a group and a channel, because it checks if the user joined this group/channel before starting commands/steps.

I checked the telegram docs and read some articles and tested manually, but didn't find and answer or approach to do that, if anyone tried or know how to trigger a bot inside a group using a link please tell me.